# OnEdit or Time based triggers to check one cell then edit another

Tags: google-sheets

My scripting skills are not the greatest but I can not figure out how to accomplish what I need to with just functions inside of Google Sheets.

My sheet looks something like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R6YJIR37wtOt8ZknSdMQPFFp0Llf_LHpmGCV32iQY00/edit#gid=1213399830

I have form responses being brought into the second tab via the Indirect function and are then modified with a ArrayFormula function to convert everything to the correct unit of measure and the summed to keep everything on the same row. All of this could be altered if needed.

I then have a column that is totaling inputs in other columns to give me my on hand inventory. We'll call this TotalsColumn.

What I am attempting to achieve is to make a script that checks the form responses, then either with:

OnEdit (which if I understand correctly does not work for information being ported in) and then alter the corresponding cell in the TotalsColumn.

or if not possible, then

With a time based trigger checking the ported information to see if there is a new entry if I don't sum it with a last function or something, or if the information remains summed (which seems easier to me) then to check if the sum is greater than it was last time it was checked and alter TotalsColumn.

The alter to the TotalsColumn, regardless of which method used, will always be a static number and I am pretty sure I'll need to make a script for each of my different inventory items but that's fine if I can just figure out a way of making this happen.

Thank for your time and any information you can provide.
Please feel free to point me to another thread where I can start to piece together a solution, I just could not find anything that related closely enough to my question or find a good jumping off point.

Comment: I think you could do this with the form submit of the sheet linked to your form.  I have to admit I'm not really sure what you want.  Have you tried any code yourself?

Comment: I've been able to figure out that onEdit will work (I tested it with a Timestamp) but I can't quite figure out the right sequence to get what I want to happen without breaking all the functions already in the sheet. The basic skeleton I have now is: 
     
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadSheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Inventory Check");
  var check101 = sheet.getRange("O2");
  var edit101 = sheet.getRange("J2");
  //formula to change the edit range on edit of check range. 
 }

Answer (score 0):

What happens in this situation?

[image]

Comment: I did run into this issue when I was getting further with the script. I am now trying to remove the sum and use a Last function of some kind to grab the actual amount I need. I'm still having a hard time trying to get the the script to behave. I have it set up with three variables, one grabbing the value of the form data, one grabbing the current value of the inventory, and one that is the current value minus the number pulled from the form. I am not trying to puzzle out how to get the script to set the value to the minus value on each edit.

Comment: Well you say:`My goal is create a formula that monitors the orange row and when a number increases it subtracts a set number from the corresponding yellow row. If the orange number decreases it will add the same set number to the corresponding yellow row.`  I was just looking for a more precise answer because I'd like to help you but I'm just not sure what want.  Have you ever tried to use google drawing to block diagram your code.  It might help you to get a handle on the flow.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1iYqWcZW5Eemb4um2TROlO_yY7l73v8ab5pn30RXKlJU/edit

Comment: *Ran out of time to edit previous comment*
This is a flow diagram I made. I'm very new to code and everything so this is hopefully a little helpful. I haven't been able to define my variable correctly in this version yet so I'm digging around trying to get that right first then figure out how to make the script change what I need it to.